# How to dynamically keep on adding items from an EditText field?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add the text written in a textfield everytime and add it into an ArrayList. For eg- if the text "abcdef" is written in the textfield, then it should get added into the list. Again if the text "ghijkl" is written in the textfield, than that should get added.

My code for adding the text into the listview:

```
final ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>(5);
String s3=text1.getText().toString();
            if(s3!=null)
                g++;
            else g--;
            if(g>0) {
                for(int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++) {
                    mylist.add(s3);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mylist.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

Is this the right way to do this? Also I am trying to get the list item for testing purpose, but I don't get any toast.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you like to add the Content of your EditText field into the list after pressing a button, so you could do it like this:

```
    // Member to store your Texts in list
    private ArrayList<String> _list = new ArrayList<>()

    // Method to call to add an entry to your list
    // Either by pressing a button, removing focus of your edit text or something else
    private void addTextToList()
    {
        String text = text1.getText().toString();
        if (text != null)
        {
            _list.add(text);
        }
    }

    private void showToast()
    {
        for(String text: _list)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, mylist.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

The toast is not shown because you need to pass your current activity.
Assuming your Code is in your activity, I passed this in the example above.

Comment: I've tried using arraylist, but everytime I add an element to it it just stays on the 0th index, and the next element that I add overwrites the 0th index's element.

Comment: In your Code example, the Problem is, that your Arraylist is in the same method as the rest of your Code. So it's a new instance every time you call your method to add the text. You could either use an Arraylist as class property like in my example or you store your Arraylist somewhere else and pass it as a Parameter to add your text. If this is not the solution, could you extend your sample above with some additional Information?

Answer (score 0):

you have to make a button to handle this action every click i make editTex ,textView and Button 
this is the action of button it every click take the value of editText and stor it in ArrayList and increse String by this value

```
public void getText(View v){

    if(ed.getText().toString().length()!=0){
        s+="\n"+ed.getText().toString();
        arr.add(ed.getText().toString());
    }
    tv.setText(s);
}
```